# Configuration with name 'default' not found while building android project on gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to import eclipse project into android studio, but its giving this error.

```
Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'D:\gradle-1.7'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HealthCity'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HealthCity'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

the same error is there when i try to manually build the project.

below is my settings.gradle

```
include ':ActionBarSherlock',':FacebookSDK',':library',':NineOldAndroids',':google-play-services_lib',':viewflow'

project(':ActionBarSherlock').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/Ankit/workspace/workspace-client-gemoro-2/ActionBarSherlock')
project(':FacebookSDK').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/Ankit/workspace/workspace-client-gemoro-2/FacebookSDK')
project(':library').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/Ankit/workspace/workspace-client-gemoro-2/library')
project(':NineOldAndroids').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/Ankit/workspace/workspace-client-gemoro-2/NineOldAndroids')
project(':google-play-services_lib').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/Ankit/workspace/workspace-client-gemoro-2/google-play-services_lib')
project(':viewflow').projectDir = new File('C:/Users/Ankit/workspace/workspace-client-gemoro-2/viewflow')
```

here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':ActionBarSherlock')
    compile project(':FacebookSDK')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':NineOldAndroids')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':viewflow')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So, you need to make sure that each submodule in your project has its own build.gradle file. The name 'default' happens because your outer build.gradle is trying to build a project that doesn't know how to build itself, thus it is given the name 'default.' Try doing that and see what happens.

Comment: What do those build.gradle files need to contain?

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide is a great resource I used for all things android-gradle. Essentially the build.gradle file for each submodule needs to have the information on how to build itself and any custom gradle command definitions.

Comment: good point, thanks! in my case the problematic submodule was an empty folder (a git submodule that i had to pull first).

Comment: You Genius "each submodule in your project has its own build.gradle file" . Thanks.

Comment: What if each submodule in my project doesn't have its own built.gradle?

Comment: The thing that clicked to me after reading this was that I was pointing to a multi-project build.gradle file instead of the specific project's I wanted from that multi-project.

Comment: it worked thanks , In my project the problem was with settings.gradle file