# How to import an external Library Android Studio 1.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, import-libraries

I can not import libraries in my project, always appears the following error:

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:library'
```

**build-gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':libraries:library')
}
```

I am using:

- https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

**UPDATE (NOT WORKS)**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.4.0'
    compile project(':libraries:library')
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot evaluate module library : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Comment: Your problem probably lies elsewhere in your `build.gradle` file, either for the app or the library. Have you tried using `compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.4.0'` rather than a local copy of the library, to see if that changes your results?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll try that and I tell you

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited, not works... same Error

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tried adding other libraries and always the same error (edited above) appears, I think I must be doing something wrong at the time of import....any suggestions?

Comment: I agree with GreyBeardedGeek's duplicate link -- the problem probably lies in how `:libraries:library` is set up.

Comment: @CommonsWare so, I should rename "build.gradle" that is within my library other than the default one?

Comment: No, but your `build.gradle` in `:libraries:library` would need to be correctly set up.

Comment: @CommonsWare I look like an idiot, but I really do not know how set-up correctly `build.gradle` in: `libraries: library` ... I am new to Android Studio, please, Can you help me do that? I am so sorry and Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you had Android Studio create the module for you, it should already have `build.gradle` there. Beyond that, you would need to edit your question to post `build.gradle` from the library. If the library does not have a `build.gradle` file, that is probably the source of your problem right there.

Answer (score 2):

As the page that you linked to says,

> Just add the dependency to your build.gradle:
>
> dependencies {
>       compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.4.0' }

Also, probably a duplicate of [Configuration with name 'default' not found while building android project on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178267/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-while-building-android-project-on-gr)

Comment: I added the dependency to my build.gradle, not works... same error. I going to read your link. Thanks