# How to import a Project from bitbucket repository to Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, repository, bitbucket

I have repository in BitBucket while cloning project

[image]

If I select "Ïmport Gradle project"

[image]

On clicking "OK" , it start building project , then gives error

[image]

If I select "Configure" to configure android project it build project but it didn't run .

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 6):

launch bitbucket.org, login to your account, select the repo which you want to import. select HTTPS and copy the link.

launch Android studio. select 'Check out the project from Version Control'
paste the link, fill in other information as asked and confirm.

this will clone your bitbucket repo in the android studio.

Answer (score 2):

BitBucket is a GitHUB based site.

You simply need to clone the repo you need to your local pc. 
Open that repo (project) in Android Studio, and Android Studio will give you the option to enable “VCS” (This is Version Control System). 
It will automatically sync with your repo, and list all your branches and so on.

You don't need to do an import, if it is already an Android Studio project.

For your error, try these as reference:

[Volley might be giving you an issue (File Structure stuff)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19583096/4180965)

[If you have modules as part of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178267/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-while-building-android-project-on-gr)

Comment: I cloned the repo in my local system after this it is giving error 


'Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.'

Comment: Refer to my answer, I have provided 2 links that might assist with that. Also, try not to do the "Import" as you say. Rather clone the repo, and open the project through android studio as you would any project. Then Gradle Sync

Comment: Yes I am not importing project i just opened and done all steps you told from scratch but still it persist unable to find why :/

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20553424/1039706)

> You need to make sure that each submodule in your project has its own build.gradle file. The name 'default' happens because your outer build.gradle is trying to build a project that doesn't know how to build itself, thus it is given the name 'default.' Try doing that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the project should give you the access to one.
Then in android studio go to VSC tab in most top bar and select
**VCS  --> git --> clone..**
Then in dialog popup in the first editbox past the 'httpsed' url and press "Clone"
Then wait untill project is clonned