# Studio Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, import-libraries

I tried to import the library "[Twitter Helper](https://github.com/krazykira/Twitter-Helper)" but I'm getting this error Configuration with name 'default' not found. I searched for its solution and I tried in many ways of importing it. But still getting the same error. It was file when I entered TwitterHelper in settings.gradle but when I added it in app/build.gradle then I'm getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178267/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-while-building-android-project-on-gr) answer.

Comment: The TwitterHelper library is of Eclipse. How to get build.gradle file in the library?